# R - Converting df with char values to numeric matrix changes values

Tags: r

I currently have a dataframe that I read in from a `.csv` file. I chopped the dataframe to remove a `datetime` column and another non-integer column using:

```
my.df <- my.df[2:7]
```

The data now looks like this:

```
  X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
1  3  4  4  4  3 76
2  3  2  3  3  3 52
3  3  3  4  3  3 64
4  3  3  4  3  3 64
5  4  4  4  4  4 80
6  3  4  4  4  3 76
7  4  4  4  4  4 80
```

I would like to use `colSums`, but I'm getting the error:

> "Error in colSums(foo) : 'x' must be numeric"

which tells me that the data is being treated as character data instead of numeric.

I have read several questions on StackOverflow that all seem to indicate that I should be using as.numeric to convert it. For example, I have tried:

```
as.matrix(sapply(my.df, as.numeric))
```

The results are:

```
     X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
[1,]  1  3  2  2  1  3
[2,]  1  1  1  1  1  1
[3,]  1  2  2  1  1  2
[4,]  1  2  2  1  1  2
[5,]  2  3  2  2  2  4
[6,]  1  3  2  2  1  3
[7,]  2  3  2  2  2  4
```

These don't even remotely match the numbers in the original data frame. What should I be doing differently?

I'm using R version 3.3.1 for `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0` (64-bit).

Comment: You've got factors at least for some of the columns and this is handled in the RFAQ and in many many questions on SO over the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mat <- sapply(my.df, function(x) as.numeric(levels(x))[x])
colSums(mat)
```

There are several things I have made for efficiency:

- `as.numeric(levels(x))[x]` is much more efficient than `as.numeric(as.character(x))`;
- use `sapply` to process your data frame `my.df`, but return a matrix `mat`, as `colSums()` works for matrix without type conversion overhead.

**Example:**

```
my.df <- data.frame(x1 = gl(3, 2, labels = c(10, 11, 12)),
                    x2 = gl(2, 3, labels = c(5, 6)))
#  x1 x2
#1 10  5
#2 10  5
#3 11  5
#4 11  6
#5 12  6
#6 12  6

data.matrix(my.df)   ## same as `sapply(my.df, as.numeric)`
#     x1 x2
#[1,]  1  1
#[2,]  1  1
#[3,]  2  1
#[4,]  2  2
#[5,]  3  2
#[6,]  3  2
```

Now try my solution:

```
mat <- sapply(my.df, function(x) as.numeric(levels(x))[x])
#     x1 x2
#[1,] 10  5
#[2,] 10  5
#[3,] 11  5
#[4,] 11  6
#[5,] 12  6
#[6,] 12  6

colSums(mat)
#x1 x2 
#66 33
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks!